# To_Json overriding in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an object in Ruby called Post.
I would like to convert post into an json but also I want to include the name of the user who posted the post. The thing is user_name is not present in Post object but the user id is.

So what I effectively want is something like this

```
{name:"My Post", body:"My post data", user_name:"jhonny"}
```

When I do a to_json on Post object I get following

```
{name:"My Post", body:"My post data"}
```

But I also want to append `user_name:"jhonny"` part also to it. I know I can make it a hash and then do a `to_json` on the hash, but I do not want to make the hash for all the post values manually as there are many attributes to post. I'd rather user a hash merge function to add the additional attribute to hash and then call json on it.

Is there a way to make a quick hash object for a ruby class? Any ideas will be welcome.

Something like

```
my_post.hash.merge{:user_name => "jhonny"}.to_json
```

Cheers.

Comment: I have found a way like
ActiveRecord::JSON.decode(my_post.to_json).merge({:user_name => "jhonny"}).to_json

This works but is a bad hack. I want a more cleaner way to get this right.

Comment: I don't think it is a bad hack. You are only changing post to json and then back to a hash then merging the user name and then converting the whole hash back to json. It would have been a bad hack if it failed in some scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering your question should be something like this

```
my_post.attributes.merge{:user_name => "jhonny"}.to_json
```

Anyway if that didn't work then just try one of the following solutions:

Add this to your `Post` model:

```
def to_json
  ActiveRecord::JSON.decode(super).merge({:user_name => user.user_name}).to_json
end
```

Another solution will be adding `user_name` method to the `Post` model:

```
def user_name
  user.user_name
end
```

Then use `to_json` as follows:

```
my_post.to_json(:methods => :username)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your Post model is ActiveRecord model, it accepts :except, :include and :only parameters for serialization methods, #to_json included. See the details and examples [here in the AR documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Serialization.html#M001873).

Basically you'll need something like

```
my_post.to_json(:include => { :user => { :only => :user_name } })
```